# Issue with a structure and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I Have this struct:

```
struct BaseLayerComponent {

    //Info
    int posX = -99999;
    int posY = -99999;

    //Texture 
    std::string textureName = NULL_STR;
    std::string localTexture = NULL_STR;
    std::string remoteTexture = NULL_STR;
    std::string remoteTextureParent = NULL_STR;
};
```

It is store in a custom array class (Actually pointers of this struct are stored).

The class that mainly using it, is **WD_MainWorld** which inherit from **WD_2DWorld**

Those two class have a function call Init(), in this function a **BaseLayerComponent** is created, then we store the ref of this last into the grid (the custom array).

But later when I want to use it,  in another function I have a weird bug (Debug function is custom function created for debugging):

```
systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[X][Y]->textureName);
systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[X][Y]->remoteTexture);
```

Here the first is working perfectly BUT the second give me an **access read violation** (Note that I've also tested it with **remoteTextureParent** but same issue).

So for debugging purpose I've created a funciton called show:

```
virtual void show() {
    systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[0][0]->remoteTexture);
}
```

And after a long time of research I've discovered where it started to bug:

this is at the end of the Init function of the parent class (last thing called);

```
   show();
   return true;
}
```

here show() works perfectly BUT when we leave the function it stop working:

```
if (!world->Init())
{
    systems->LastErrMsg = "Main World can't be initialized";
    ErrSubmit(systems->ErrSys, EXO::ERR::LOG_TYPE::ERR, ERR_MAIN_WORLD_INIT, systems->LastErrMsg, "Main World Class - Can't be Initialized");
    return false;
}
else
    world->show();
```

Remember that textureName still working and I have tested pointer are still good (still the same address).

Thanks, in advance.

UPDATE:

I have changed the show function to test everything:

```
virtual void show() {

    std::cout << layer0.Grid[0][0] << std::endl;

    std::cout << layer0.Grid[0][0]->posX << std::endl;
    std::cout << layer0.Grid[0][0]->posY << std::endl;

    systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[0][0]->localTexture);
    systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[0][0]->textureName);
    systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[0][0]->remoteTextureParent);
    systems->ErrSys->Debug(layer0.Grid[0][0]->remoteTexture);
}
```

and here is the Output:

Before the end of Init():

```
0073EED8
0
0
src/World/DGI_New_Tile_Normal.png
DGI_New_Tile_Normal.png
http://rpg.exodiastudio.com/
TEMP/World/Main/Textures/DGI_New_Tile_Normal.png
```

After Init():

```
0073EED8
-858993460
0
  <- There is a space here
  <- and here the error (which is not same as previous, see below):
```

Unhandled exception at 0x756422A2 in RPGBoards.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0073E784.

UPDATE 2 (For Jabberwocky):

Init in **WD_MainWorld**:
    //First we create a EGE world in the main interface (Using connection)
    EXO::IO::INTERFACES_GAME_TYPE Type = EXO::IO::INTERFACES_GAME_TYPE::GM;

```
//Creating Builder (What world need);
EXO::TREATEMENT::WORLD::World_Builder Builder;
Builder.background = "black";
Builder.isMovable = true;



//Sending all textures
systems->FTP->CreateFolder(root, 0);
systems->FTP->CreateFolder(root + "Main", 0);
systems->FTP->CreateFolder(root + "Main/Textures", 0);



//Creating default tile
EXO::TREATEMENT::WORLD::BaseLayerComponent comp;
comp.posX = 0;
comp.posY = 0;
comp.localTexture = "src/World/DGI_New_Tile_Normal.png";
comp.textureName = "DGI_New_Tile_Normal.png";

//First we update the online texture path
comp.remoteTexture = root + "Main/Textures/" + comp.textureName;
comp.remoteTextureParent = "http://rpg.exodiastudio.com/";

//now we send texture
bool isDone = false;
systems->FTP->SendFile(comp.localTexture, comp.remoteTexture, 0, &isDone);

while (!isDone);

Builder.baseLayerComponents.push_back(comp);
AddTile(comp);


systems->connection->CallFunction("AddWorld", &Type, &Builder);


show();
return WD_2DWorld::Init();
```

Init in the parent class **WD_2DWorld**:

```
//First we check if systems are active because the class need it
if (systems == nullptr || GC == nullptr)
    return false;


//Creating all layers
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    EXO::TREATEMENT::WORLD::Layer newLayer;
    newLayer.layerLevel = i;
    layers.push_back(newLayer);
}

//set has initialized and return
classInitialized = true;


return true;
```

Comment: -858993460 in hexadecimal is 0xcccccccc which is a special value local variables are initialized to in MSVC debug builds. It sounds you're using an uninitialized local variable somewhere in your code. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-a-compiler-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-fre), it's somewhat OT, but very useful.

Comment: Yes but as you can see the variable was initialize before the return and right after it is not. but nothing happened between.

Comment: I don't know what `init()` does because you didn't post the code, but it definitely messes something up. Have a close look at `init()`, simplify it until the bug goes away. Divide and conquer.

Comment: As I said the in the post I've did it, and till the return it woks fine but when when exist the function it stop working.

Comment: Without seeing the `init` function I can't say much more. Also be aware that anything called by `init()` can mess up things too. Also google "undefined behaviour C".

Comment: I can't publish the function if you want ??

Comment: If it's not too long, yes

Comment: I've updated it

Comment: Your code is incomplete, it's impossible ton help. I'm giving up.